# Non-zero Hamiltonian matrix elements in a generic QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

Consider a generic QFT. Let's assume that all the charge operators (momentum, electric charge, etc.) commute with both free and full Hamiltonians. For simplicity, let us also assume that all the charge operators are diagonal in the Fock basis (of the free theory):
\begin{alignat}{9}
\text{Free theory:}\quad&[Q_i, H_0] &&= 0 \quad&&,\\
\text{Full theory:}\quad&[Q_i, H_{full}] &&= 0 \quad&&.\\
\end{alignat}
$Q_i$ and $H_0$ are diagonal, while $H_{full}$ is non-diagonal — pretty much like in most realistic theories. Consider two Fock states $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$ whose quantum numbers are equal (all but energy — the latter is not defined for those, since they are not the eigenstates of the full theory).

**Should I expect that all the Hamiltonian's matrix elements**
$$\langle\beta|H_{full}|\alpha\rangle$$
**are non-vanishing?** If so, it would be great if someone could prove this for  a particular model (like QED). Or, if this is not true, give an explicit example of a theory and two states such that the Hamiltonian's matrix element is zero. What could physically cause vanishing of such a matrix element?

Comment: I mean, if $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$ are two distinct eigenstates of $H$, then their matrix element vanishes. So there definitely EXIST kets for which that matrix element vanishes (unless your quantum numbers exhaust the eigenspace). Is that all you're looking for?

Comment: I was probably unclear, the interaction Hamiltonian is not diagonal, only the free one and the charges.

Comment: "Not diagonal" with respect to what basis? It's certainly diagonal in some basis!

Comment: I'm only talking about the Fock space corresponding to the free theory.

Comment: Consider a QM of two complex fermion. The free theory has $H=0.$ Now add interactions $-m(\psi^1\psi^2+h.c.), H_{full}=m(\psi^1\psi^2+\bar{\psi}^2\bar{\psi}^1).$ Then between the 4 states you can have $|0\rangle, \bar{\psi}^1|0\rangle, \bar{\psi}^2|0\rangle,\bar{\psi}^1\bar{\psi}^2|0\rangle,$ lots of the matrix elements of $H_{full}$ are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Consider for instance $(\phi_i^2)^2$ theory in any dimension $d$, where $\phi_i$ transforms in the fundamental of $O(N)$. (This is usually just called the $O(N)$ model.) There is a Fock space of modes $a_i^\dagger(\mathbf{p})$ and $a_i(\mathbf{p})$. The only charges $Q_i$ are the generators of $O(N)$. Let $|\alpha>$ and $|\beta>$ both be scalar states, such that $Q_i | \alpha > = Q_i |\beta > = 0$; this means that they have the same quantum numbers. However, let $| \alpha > $ be a state with $k$ particles and let $| \beta > $ have $k'$ particles. Then
$$
< \alpha | H | \beta > = 0
$$ if $|k - k'| > 4$, for the simple reason that the vertex $(\phi_i^2)^2$ cannot create or destroy more than 4 particles. QED.

Comment: Isn't your statement tree-level-perturbative?

Comment: Also, couldn't we use smth like a $2\to3$ matrix element as a counter-example?

Comment: @mavzolej The Hamiltonian itself is tree-level, right? It's of the form $H_\text{full} = H_0 + g V$. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are complicated functions of $g$, but that's not what matters in your question - I exhibit some Fock states that have zero matrix elements with the Hamiltonian $H_\text{full}$.

Comment: @mavzolej The $2 \rightarrow 3$ matrix element vanishes as a consequence of the global symmetry transformation $\phi^i \mapsto - \phi^i$, which is part of $O(N)$.

Comment: Ohhh now I got it. Many thanks, that's what I needed.